# Define the structure of an untitled document in Spyder

Tags: python, spyder

I used to know how to do that with Spyder back when Python 2.# was the rage. Been a few years since and I just started programming again so memory isn't what it used to be.

Using "Spyder 3.1.3" I want to be able to tell it that when I click "New Document" (toolbar button or with File menu) to open an untitled document with the "import" code already typed. I use those packages the most.

Ex:
Current "Untitled.py":

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Wed Apr 19 10:05:42 2017

@author: Someone
"""
```

What I want is:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Wed Apr 19 10:05:42 2017

@author: Someone
"""
import numpy as np
import prettyplotlib as ppl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import math
from math import pi as pi
import pint
from prettyplotlib import brewer2mpl

ureg = pint.UnitRegistry()
set2 = brewer2mpl.get_map('Set2', 'qualitative', 8).mpl_colors
#color=set2[]
```

Can this be done with Spyder 3.#??

Thanks in advance all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow this route from the main menu: *Tools → Preferences → Editor → Advanced settings*.  There press the button *Edit template for new modules*.  Edit and save the `template.py`.